# How to use AzCopy to work in Azure web app service using cmd

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azcopy

I have facing one issue.
I am using AzCopy to copy my files to blob storage. currently I used VM to host my application. I am able to move data to blob.

Now I have migrated the code into Azure PaaS i.e. azure app service. now issue is I am not able to execute the AzCopy.exe using cmd and c# code.

Thanks,
Dattatray

Comment: Could you elaborate? What did you mean by "not able to execute"? Did you meet any error message? Or do you have any difficulties in setting up the command line in PaaS?

Comment: Actually I am able to run normal echo msg command through my c# code in Azure web app which I hosted. but if I wanted to run AzCopy.exe in the same code then it's not work. Their is no error msg.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use AzCopy without running a VM, you can use [Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).  AzCopy is installed on the containers that run both the PowerShell and Bash shell environments.  AzCopy is **NOT** installed in the sandbox that your Azure Web App runs in so you will not be able to run in from the web app console.  If you need to call the AzCopy exe from your web code, you could use a webjob that has the AzCopy.exe in it.  See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs).

Comment: I used the web jobs to run this exe and use the c# code to run my web job through c# + API code. Thanks a lot. I just wanted to know is why this AzCopy is not in web app sandbox after all this is the Microsoft feature.

Comment: I am not on the product group for Web Apps so I can only speculate they don't have it to keep the install base lean and on less dependency to keep up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

Bring up a console using Advanced Tools in your web app UI portal.  You should see the folder d:\devtools\azcopy.  You will find the executable there.