# I want to backup specific files and folder of my web app to the blob storage using Powershell

Tags: azure, api, powershell, azure-blob-storage, kudu

My web app has large number of files and folders but i want only specific files/folder to backup and then store them into blob storage.
This approch is for disaster recovery.

Code :

```
$domain = "Resonate"
$user = "abc" 
$pw = "****"

$securepwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pw -asplaintext -force
$account = $($domain)+"\"+$($user) 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($account,$securepwd) 

$username = "`$abc"
$password = "***"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$filePath = "C:\Users\Raj.Negi\Desktop\PowerShell\Web.config"
$apiUrl = "https://abc.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/Web.config"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Credential $credential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method GET -OutFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

Connect-AzureRmAccount

$acctKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name abcdemo -ResourceGroupName abcRG).Value[0]

$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "abcdemo" -StorageAccountKey $acctKey

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $filePath -Container "abccontainer" -BlobType "Block" -Context $storageContext -Verbose
```

Currently it download one file into my local path and then upload it to the azure blob. I want that it should directly upload it to blob without download it to local path.
It may be one file or the complete folder.

Microsoft provide the way to partial backup of your web app by excluding the content but it is useless for large application. It is better if they provide only selected files/folders backup.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the origin where your files are stored before backing them up to Azure ? Are these files local ?

Comment: Did you try to implement it with code.

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT Files is on cloud as it is web app. I can access through kudu or App Service Editor. I want to download it and upload it to blob container.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I am trying to do it using powershell so that later on i can use it using runbook.

Comment: @rAJ, it's hard to use powershell runbook to complete it(due to some limitations). You can consider azure webjobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience, the simple way to backup some files and directories to Azure Blob Storage is to use AzCopy, and you can combine it with Azure Triggered WebJob on Azure WebApp to satisfy your needs.

Here is my steps to realize for backuping resources under `D:\home` of Azure WebApp to Blob Storage.

1. I tried to use AzCopy [v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) (only x64 version) to copy a single file to Azure Blob Storage on Kudo Console, but failed due to some reason about `Access is denied`. However, AzCopy [v8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) on Windows works in Kudo Console.
2. First, I installed AzCopy v8 on my local Windows machine, and upload the `AzCopy` directory under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure` into Kudo Console path `D:\home`, as the figure below.
   [image]
3. I tried to upload a single file to my container `test` via command `AzCopy /Source:D:\home\site\test /Dest:https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/test /DestKey:<account key> /Pattern:"example.txt"` under the path `D:\home\AzCopy`, it works.
4. I tried to upload a directory to my virtual directory `backup` of container `test` via command `D:\home\AzCopy\AzCopy /Source:D:\home\site\test /Dest:https://ppas.blob.core.windows.net/test/backup /DestKey:b7AzhS60+0hgTWGJdaxXT0w4O6hGuoiL0UVwcLJWIwq/w6hJzKwvt9asFdpfx0yif73ghvLe6urLIo8h6CtZnw== /S /Y` without confirmation prompts, it works too.
5. So I make a `.bat` file `backup.bat` to write command lines below using the absolute path as the steps above to upload it as a triggered webjob like the figure below. Also, you can make a powershell script to do the same.

   ```
   D:\home\AzCopy\AzCopy /Source:D:\home\site\test /Dest:https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/backup /DestKey:<account key> /Pattern:"example.txt" /Y
   D:\home\AzCopy\AzCopy /Source:D:\home\site\test /Dest:https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/backup /DestKey:<account key> /S /Y
   ```

[image]

It works as expected.
[image]

Comment: It appears that both azcopy v10 and v8 are in D:\devtools folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157936/532675